# Scala Junit - NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function1

Tags: scala, junit

I am trying to run a Scala Junit 4 test, but I get `NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function1`. I am starting it through a run configuration.

Anyone know what the issue is?

Full error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function1
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.isJUnit3SetUpTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Function1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Usually this means that the Scala library is not on the classpath or something else is misconfigured. Please share some environment info, run config setup to make it easier for us.

Comment: @AkosKrivachy Thanks for the help, you were right about Scala-library not being in the classpath for my test run configuration. I added it as an external JAR and it worked. The Scala-library jar is listed in my project in Eclipse and running tests using Maven works, so why was it not found by the run configuration?

Answer (score 2):

I was having similar issue, when I was working `akka-http-2.11` which was built with `scala 2.11.*` but I was using `scala-2.12.4` in classpath.

Error was

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Function1$class

    at akka.stream.Supervision$$anon$1.<init>(Supervision.scala:57)
    at akka.stream.Supervision$.<init>(Supervision.scala:57)
    at akka.stream.ActorMaterializerSettings$.apply(ActorMaterializer.scala:258)
    at akka.stream.ActorMaterializerSettings$.apply(ActorMaterializer.scala:248)
    at akka.stream.ActorMaterializer$$anonfun$1.apply(ActorMaterializer.scala:41)
    at akka.stream.ActorMaterializer$$anonfun$1.apply(ActorMaterializer.scala:41)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at akka.stream.ActorMaterializer$.apply(ActorMaterializer.scala:41)
    at akka.stream.ActorMaterializer$.create(ActorMaterializer.scala:110)
```

***(see `build.gradle` below)***

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version: '2.12.4'
    compile group: 'com.typesafe.akka', name: 'akka-actor_2.12', version: '2.5.6'
    compile group: 'com.typesafe.akka', name: 'akka-http-experimental_2.11', version: '2.4.11.2'
}
```

**FIX was to use same version of scala (`2.11`) across all dependencies.**

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version: '2.11.11'
    compile group: 'com.typesafe.akka', name: 'akka-actor_2.12', version: '2.5.6'
    compile group: 'com.typesafe.akka', name: 'akka-http-experimental_2.11', version: '2.4.11.2'
}
```

So, make sure you have same version of scala being used.